# Node-red: get current flow name at runtime

Tags: node-red

I am trying to get the current flow name when a message passes through. I figured out how to get the flow id (from config.z) but could not find the flow name anywhere at runtime. The nodered docs mention that there is an api method to get a flow (https://nodered.org/docs/api/runtime/api#getFlow) but this does not work either- I get an error when I try RED.nodes.getFlow(id)
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That admin API method is meant to be an external http endpoint, not a way for javascript in a function node to get information. Are you trying to get the flow name from within a function node, or in a custom node's runtime code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I am trying to get the flow name from inside a custom node's runtime code.

Comment: You need to update your question to let us know what you are trying to achieve. Your node should not need to know anything about it's flow.

Comment: I am writing a custom node which will add the current flow name to the msg going through it. This will be used by other function nodes which will read the msg property. Please tell me if you want me to clarify this further

Comment: The question is fairly clear, and so is the fact that any node's runtime code does not have access to the current flow's name, only its *id* (by design). Personally, I don't understand why that could not be made available -- but you will need to start that discussion on the mailing list in order to help the developers understand the need. Generally, any ideas that help the community and fit the design model are quickly integrated into node-red.

Comment: I have a use case. I'm wanting to build a node to send alerts via Alertzy. Alertzy sends popup alerts to your phone from a simple POST to their server. I wanted to make it so the Title attribute defaults to the flow name to make it easier to only provide the Message attribute and have the alert categorized in a logical way on the phone. I have no interest in making decisions based on the flow name, I just want it to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an approach that is generally supported by flow-based programming. No node should know anything much about the previous nodes in the flow other than what is set in the msg that is passed.

To achieve what you want, simply add a msg.topic with an identifier. Or indeed, some other identifying property. You can do this using a number of different nodes.

If you need more information, you will need to explain **why** you want a flow identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
[{"id":"dda94d1c.3a07a","type":"change","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"jsonata filter","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filter","pt":"msg","to":"payload[type = 'tab']","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":450,"y":140,"wires":[["35ac9568dc03889e","a1236f1606f29afb"]]},{"id":"1624601c.23f32","type":"inject","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload","v":"","vt":"str"},{"p":"topic","v":"flows","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"flows","payload":"","payloadType":"str","x":90,"y":140,"wires":[["312ff7a6.7dd008","25dffcf394cf2d38"]]},{"id":"312ff7a6.7dd008","type":"http request","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"Get {{{topic}}}","method":"GET","ret":"obj","paytoqs":"ignore","url":"http://localhost:1880/red/{{{topic}}}","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"basic","senderr":false,"x":260,"y":140,"wires":[["dda94d1c.3a07a","35ac9568dc03889e"]]},{"id":"25dffcf394cf2d38","type":"function","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"getnodeId","func":"msg.payload=node.id;\nmsg.topic=\"myNodeId\"\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":240,"y":220,"wires":[["8814365228f00a6b","a1236f1606f29afb"]]},{"id":"8814365228f00a6b","type":"debug","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":410,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"35ac9568dc03889e","type":"debug","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":690,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"a1236f1606f29afb","type":"join","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","mode":"custom","build":"array","property":"","propertyType":"full","key":"topic","joiner":"\\n","joinerType":"str","accumulate":false,"timeout":"2","count":"2","reduceRight":false,"reduceExp":"","reduceInit":"","reduceInitType":"num","reduceFixup":"","x":650,"y":200,"wires":[["1dc90a3eb71f3896","39cc8f1920cfadd9"]]},{"id":"1dc90a3eb71f3896","type":"debug","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":850,"y":200,"wires":[]},{"id":"39cc8f1920cfadd9","type":"function","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"FindMyNodeName","func":"if(msg.payload[0].topic==\"myNodeId\")\n{\n    var y=0;\n    var x=1;\n}\nelse\n{\n    var y=1;\n    var x=0;\n}\n\n\nlet nod=msg.payload[x].payload.find(o => o.id === msg.payload[y].payload);\nmsg.MyFlowName=msg.payload[x].filter.find(o => o.id === nod.z).label;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":890,"y":160,"wires":[["7e7e3376fb0e8db4"]]},{"id":"7e7e3376fb0e8db4","type":"debug","z":"c6102b2d.d908e8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"MyFlowName","targetType":"msg","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":1090,"y":160,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: A flow without out any explanation about how it works is near useless, please edit this answer to include a description of how it works or it is likely to be downvoted and deleted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work. I get: `node: FindMyNodeName, function : (error): "TypeError: msg.payload[x].payload.find is not a function"

Comment: This is because you are not able to call localhost:1880/flows -> and it's probably because you are using newer node-red version as was my code developed. Probably Admin http API block your connection to flows. Read this documentation how to improve it: https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/flows/   Second option but I did not try it is change settings file. Add this:"httpStatic: __dirname" in your settings file. but this is not really recommended from security point of view. What you need to achieve is read your flows.json by localhost:1880/flows to be able to search in that file.